# Finding file name/location of bash script running on server using PID

Tags: shell-script, centos, command-line

As a training exercise for the new company I work for, a buddy put a script on my webserver that displays `( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)` on the top right hand corner of my CLI screen then shelled into the server.

Using `ps -ef` I have found the running script:

```
root     20071     1  0 Oct07 ?        00:03:04 bash
```

I have attempted to run:

```
ps -p 20071 -o comm=
```

Which outputs = `bash`

I have also attempted `l -la /proc/20071/exe`

Which outputs =

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct  7 21:03 /proc/20071/exe -> /bin/bash*
```

I am in the `usr/bin/` where I believe the script to be located, but I cannot seem to isolate it as I do not see `bash` referenced within that folder.

I am fairly new to CLI, so I know I must be missing something obvious. Is the script itself called bash, or is that just displaying the type?  I am assuming the script is a .sh file, but I am unsure.

Is there a way to determine the same of the script that is running and where it is located either using PID or another method?

Comment: Try `man motd`.

Comment: I opened that file with nano and vim but it is blank in both cases.

Comment: I think you need to provide some more details. That face appears in your terminal when you log in. Does it stay there as you execute commands, or does it scroll off the screen as you enter commands?

Comment: Thanks for getting back, Glenn.  The message scrolls away and I see other instances of it popping up.  Seems to have 7 or 8 instances of the process running.  Not sure what triggers it, but the processes all have the same name and date as the example in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bash script, so the process is executing `/bin/bash`. That's normal.

The script is open by the bash process. Use `ls -l /proc/20071/fd` or `lsof -p 20071` to lists the files open by that process. You'll find the script on file descriptor 255 by default.

```
cat /proc/20071/fd/255
```

(Whether this is what's causing the phonetic symbols and diacritics to appear on your terminal, and how it's doing it, are separate matters for which you do not have sufficient information at this time.)